# How to authenticate Central Authentication Service(CAS) with sqlmap?

Tags: sql-injection, cas, sqlmap

I have a problem with CAS. I have a website which has several applications based on CAS and I want to do some SqlInjection tests in order to close holes in the system as much as possible. But because of the ticket system of CAS, I couldn't pass the login screen with [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/). How can I login to the site, by providing username and password via sqlmap?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTTP Cookie header](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/doc/README.html#ss5.3), switches: `--cookie`

```
python sqlmap.py -u 'http://www.your-website.org/?id=1' --dbms=mysql --cookie 'pass=123456789123456789123456789;uid=2'
```

that the HTTP Cookie header values are usually separated by a ; character, not by an &.
Sqlmap can recognize these as separate sets of parameter=value too, as well as GET and POST parameters.